# Average distance of the mean of $n$ random complex numbers in a unit disc

Tags: pr.probability, mg.metric-geometry, geometric-probability

Let $z_1,z_2,\dots,z_n$ be $n$ complex numbers distributed uniformly and randomly over the unit disc $x^2+y^2 \leq 1$. Let $z$ be the complex number  defined by the mean of the of these numbers,that is,
$$ z=\frac1n \sum_{i=1}^{n} z_i.$$
Numerical simulations reveal that $E(|z|)$ exists. I want to know if there is some analytical way of finding a closed form expression for the expected radial distance of $z$ in terms of $n$? Any hints/responses will be greatly appreciated . The graph shows the variation of $E(|z|)$ with $n$ [image]

Comment: This seems like a difficult version of an "expected distance of random walk from the origin" type of result, but I can't find a clearly related result. Usually the length of each step is fixed (here, it is random), and only the direction is random.

Comment: The value for $n=1$ is $\frac{2}{3}$, which can be shown by solving a two-dimensional integral. Solving the 4-dimensional integral for $n=2$ should be withing reach, perhaps.

Comment: For $n=1$ it is simply $\int_0^1 \sqrt{x} dx = 2/3$ because the direction does not matter and the distance from zero of each $z_i$ is distributed as the square root of a  uniformly  distributed random variable on $[0, 1]$. The case $n=2$ seems much harder.

Comment: I calculated numerically the value for $n=2$ and I have a conjecture as to what the exact value might be: https://mathoverflow.net/q/395659

Comment: Along the same lines as Kluyver,"A local probability problem" (1906), one can derive that $|\sum_{i=1}^n z_i |$ has density $\rho(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^\infty dt\, t\,J_0(x\, t) ( 2J_1(t) / t)^n$.

Comment: @TimothyBudd could you kindly say how to start

Comment: I’m not sure if you are also interested in bounds, but it’s easy to compute $E|z|^2=\frac1{2n}$, which implies $E|z|<\sqrt{\frac2n}$ or so.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek ,Yes i am interested in the bounds as well.Could you kindly explain  it a bit more how we go about finding these bounds?

Comment: $E|z|^2=\frac1{2n}$ follows by direct computation, using linearity of expectation and independence of the $z_i$’s: $E|z|^2=E\frac1{n^2}\bigl(\sum_iz_i\bigr)\bigl(\sum_i\overline z_i\bigr)=\frac1{n^2}\sum_{i,j}Ez_i\overline z_j=\frac1{n^2}\sum_iE|z_i|^2=\frac1{2n}$. Then $\Pr(|z|\ge t)=\Pr(|z|^2\ge t^2)\le\frac1{2nt^2}$ by Markov’s inequality, hence $E|z|=\int_0^\infty\Pr(|z|\ge t)\,dt\le\frac1{\sqrt{2n}}+\int_{1/\sqrt{2n}}^\infty\frac{dt}{2nt^2}=\frac2{\sqrt{2n}}=\sqrt{\frac2n}$. But note that the bound in esg’s answer, albeit asymptotic, is better: $E|z|=\sqrt{\frac\pi{8n}}(1+o(1))$.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://mathoverflow.net/q/394883/37212, https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/510167/2921, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4030410/14578.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 5):

Here is another method.

Since the uniform distribution on the unit disk is rotationally symmetric (invariant under orthogonal transformations), the problem can be reduced to a random walk problem in $\mathbb{R}$.

Let $Z_1,Z_2,\ldots$ be independent, and identically uniformly distributed on the unit disk, with $Z_i=(X_i,Y_i)$.
Clearly $X_1,X_2\ldots$ are i.i..d with density $p(x)=\frac{2}{\pi}\sqrt{1-x^2}1_{[-1,1]}(x)$.

For any rotationally symmetric
random vector $V=(V_1,V_2)$ with finite expectation of $|V|:=\sqrt{V_1^2+V_2^2}$  it holds that
$$\mathbb{E}(|V|)=\frac{\pi}{2}\mathbb{E}(|V_1|)$$
Applying this to $Z^{(n)}:=                                 |Z_1+\ldots+Z_n|$ we get that

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}\big(\frac{Z^{(n)}}{n}\big)&=\frac{1}{n}\frac{\pi}{2}\mathbb{E}|X_1+\ldots + X_n|\\
                                 &=\frac{1}{n}\big(\frac{2}{\pi}\big)^{n-1}\,\int_{-1}^1\ldots\int_{-1}^1|x_1+\ldots+x_n|\prod_{i=1}^n\sqrt{1-x_i^2}\,dx_1\,\ldots dx_n\\
                                 \end{align*}

The integrals can be solved explicitly for $n=1$ and $n=2$, but that seems to be as far as it goes. But (using the central limit theorem and uniform integrability) it is easy to see that $$\mathbb{E}\big(\frac{Z^{(n)}}{\sqrt{n}}\big)\longrightarrow \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{8}}$$

**Remarks:**
(1) a related problem appeared here [An interesting triple integral](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/300134/an-interesting-triple-integral)
(2) for similar considerations see Feller II (1971), p. 30 ff

Comment: @sajjad veeri: for $n=3$ see my answer to the follow-up post by Moritz Firsching.

Answer (score 2):

This does not answer the question, but reformulates it as an integration problem and addresses a question asked in the comments.
Conditionally on $|z_1| = a_1$, ..., $|z_n| = a_n$, the probability that $x<c$ was computed in [Kluyver, "A local probability problem" (1906)](https://www.dwc.knaw.nl/DL/publications/PU00013859.pdf) to be
$$
\mathbb{P}\Big( \big|\sum_{i=1}^n z_i\big| < c \,\Big|\, |z_i|=a_i \Big) = c \int_0^\infty J_1(uc)\prod_{i=1}^n J_0(u a_i)\,\mathrm{d}u.
$$
Using that $\int_0^1 2a\,J_0(u a) \mathrm{d}a = 2 J_1(u) /u$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial c}( c J_1(u c)) = uc J_0(u c)$, this gives the density as
$$
\rho(x) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\mathbb{P}\Big( \big|\sum_{i=1}^n z_i\big| < x\Big) = \int_0^\infty xu J_0(ux) \,\left(\tfrac{2}{u}J_1(u)\right)^n\mathrm{d}u.
$$
(Note: there was a small mistake in the formula given in the comments.)
By construction $\int_0^n\rho(x)\,\mathrm{d}x = 1$ as $\rho(x)$ vanishes for $x > n$.
Hence
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\Big( \frac{1}{n}\big|\sum_{i=1}^n z_i\big|\Big) &= \frac{1}{n} \int_0^n \mathrm{d}x \int_0^\infty \mathrm{d}u\, x^2u\, J_0(ux) \left(\tfrac{2}{u}J_1(u)\right)^n \\
&= \frac{n^2}{3} \int_0^\infty u\,{_1F_2}(\tfrac{3}{2};1,\tfrac{5}{2}; -\tfrac14 n^2u^2) \left(\tfrac{2}{u}J_1(u)\right)^n,
\end{align}
where the second integral was kindly provided by mathematica.

One could hope to extract some exact values for $n\geq 3$ from Borwein, Jonathan M. "A short walk can be beautiful." Journal of Humanistic Mathematics 6, no. 1 (2016): 86-109.

Comment: From the above answers and comments ,we can conclude that the average  of centre of mass  of all n-gons for large n approaches origin .Can it admit of some geometrical or physical proof?